# Convergence of series involving $\tan()$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+n}\cdot \tan^2(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\cdot{n}^x$ converges.

For large $n$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is small so $\tan^2(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\sim (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $S \sim \sum \frac{n^x}{(n^2+n)n}=\sum \frac{n^x}{n^2(n+1)}$.

$\forall n\geq 1:\frac{n^x}{n^2(n+1)} < \frac{n^x}{n^2} $ , so I just have to find the convergence of $\sum \frac{n^x}{n^2}$.

Where do I go from here? What test do I use to find convergence?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the ratio test. When $n$ is large, what is the ratio between terms?